# How to make Tesseract recognize hyphens or minus signs?

Tags: r, machine-learning, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I want to use tesseract to read the grades on a graduation diploma. These are in a table-like structure as you can see here: https://www.asv.bayern.de/doku/gy/oberstufe/zeugnis/abitur

Since tesseract is not actually designed to read tables, I break the table into individual columns, have tesseract read these values, and then merge the columns back together. I can then also transfer these into a tibble. I found the idea for this here: https://themockup.blog/posts/2021-01-18-reading-tables-from-images-with-magick/

This way I manage very well to consider the individual column types (character or integer). But there is a problem. As you can hopefully see, there are not grades in all rows or columns. These empty cells are filled with a hyphen "-". However, Tesseract does not recognize these hyphens, which is why the individual list elements have different amounts of values. This also causes the column lengths to be different, which is why I can't merge them into one tibble.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to also identify hyphens so that they won't be ignored. The columns should all have the same length so that I can join them into one tibble.

Attached is the code I am currently using. It's basically the same as in the MockUp Blog tutorial but with individual adjustmens. For example, I've added the hyphen (-), underscore (_) and dot (.) in the Whitelist. The individual crop areas correspond to those on my original certificates, which of course I do not show here. I hope you will understand this.

I would be very happy about your support, thanks in advance!

```
# Only need to do download once:
tesseract_download("deu")

Now load the dictionary
(deutsch <- tesseract("deu"))

abiturzeugnis <- pdftools::pdf_convert('./example.pdf', dpi = 600)

text <- tesseract::ocr(abiturzeugnis, engine = deutsch)
cat(text)

#####
library(pdftools)

bitmap <- pdf_render_page('./example.pdf', page = 2, dpi = 600)
dim(bitmap)
bitmap

abiturzeugnis <- image_read(bitmap)

no_grid <- abiturzeugnis %>%
image_deskew() %>% 
#image_convert(type = 'Bilevel') %>% 
image_quantize(colorspace = "gray") %>% 
image_transparent(color = "white", fuzz=30) %>%
image_background("white")

library(tidyverse)

img_ocr_fun <- function(trim_width, trim_start, char_num = TRUE) {
num_only <- tesseract::tesseract(    
options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = c("._-0123456789 "))
)
combo <- tesseract::tesseract(
options = list(
  tessedit_char_whitelist = paste0(
    c(letters, LETTERS, " ", "._0123456789 (-)", "ä", "ö", "ü", "Ä", "Ö", "Ü"), collapse = "")
))

 input_char <- if (isTRUE(char_num)) {
num_only
} else {
combo
}
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(trim_width, 3180, trim_start, 1400)) %>%
ocr(engine = input_char) %>%
str_split(pattern = "\n") %>%
unlist() %>%
enframe() %>%
select(-name) %>%
filter(!is.na(value), str_length(value) > 0)
}

c(
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(750, 3180, 270, 1400)),
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(115, 3180, 1210, 1400)),
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(105, 3180, 1460, 1400)),
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(100, 3180, 1700, 1400)),
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(100, 3180, 1950, 1400)),
no_grid %>%
image_crop(geometry_area(600, 3180, 2125, 1400))
) %>%
image_append() %>%
image_ggplot()

all_ocr <- list(trim_width = c(750, 115, 105, 100, 100, 600),
            trim_start = c(270, 1210, 1460, 1700, 1950, 2125),
            char_num = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%  
purrr::pmap(img_ocr_fun) 

all_ocr

data_df <- all_ocr %>% 
bind_cols() %>% 
set_names(nm = "Fach", "11 I", "11 II", "12 I", "12 II", "Note") 

data_df
```

Comment: See tesseract argument PSMs for reading columns better. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Can you explain me, how to change the PSM in R? I just find the 'tessedit_pageseg_mode' parameter which I can set like the 'whitelist' parameter.

However, I guess that this is not the same as the Page Segmentation Method. When I look it up, i only find tutorials for the Ubunto command line but nothing for R. It would be great if you could help me with that!

Comment: Can you not call tesseract externally from within R?  Sorry, I do not know R.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Unfortunatelly not ... yet. I really prefer R since this is the programming language I know the best. If there's no way to change the page segmentation method directly in R, I have to find another solution, maybe using Python...

Comment: Sorry, I do not know R.